# xmlhttp.open(url) and Calling php function using AJAX not working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Just beginner in php, I want to call php method using AJAX. I tried every thing but don't know what error is. Not getting any response from object xmlhttp.

Heres my java script code :

```
function loadData(){
    var mID=ddItems;
    var method=2;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../code/GetItemsInDD.class.php?id=" + mID + "&method=" + method, true); **// is this statement correct**

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) **//conditin is false,**
        {
            document.getElementById("ddItems").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
     }
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

My js file is on "projectname/javascript/script.js" and my php file is in "projectname/code/GetItemsInDD.class.php" dir.

Comment: Using a javascript library like jquery would make your life a lot easier

Comment: what is the error you are getting in firebug or chrome's javascript console

Comment: Pretty sure you have to bind the `.onreadystatechange` *before* you call `.open`, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: In your PHP are you handling the method param and calling the appropriate function using call_user_func?

Comment: @Satya no error but last if statement is not execyting, is my   xmlhttp.open statement correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use jQuery for making AJAX requests? Its as simple as this, include jQuery in your page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and JS code,

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '../code/GetItemsInDD.class.php?id=" + mID + "&method=" + method',
  success: function (data) {
     document.getElementById("ddItems").innerHTML = data; 
  }
});
```

This way, you don't need to check for the readyState and status thing

jQuery follows object oriented approach for declaring `XMLHttpRequest` objects, so you won't have to worry about creating multiple objects for making more than one AJAX requests.

Comment: i have just basic understanding of jquery any example, Is it complete example.

Comment: @Mayur example as in? the above code shows how do you make an AJAX request in JQuery as well as how to use the response.

Comment: @Mayur Of course it is complete, except how to include the JQuery in the page. that too, I have added, what else were you expecting?

Comment: thanks for you help, right now what I am reading, how to ajax in jquery.

Comment: This response doesn't help the question asked, since you are telling the OP to use JQuery and not simple JS. Those who searched for and selected the question are expecting JS solutions.

Comment: This is the case where giving the "answer" didn't seem to be sufficient. Apparently OP didn't know how and what needed to be done. I gave him a direction and it helped. There are plenty of questions/articles explaining how to use `XMLHttpRequest` for different cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
     function loadData(){
           var xmlhttp;
           var mID=ddItems;
           var method=2;
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
             else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
               {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
            document.getElementById("ddItems").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
           }
           xmlhttp.open("GET", "../code/GetItemsInDD.class.php?id=" + mID + "&method=" + method, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made 2 desired changes to your code, try running it now. Make sure the URL is correct.

```
function loadData()
{
var mID=ddItems;

var method=2;

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else    //For some versions of IE
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) **//conditin is false,**
    {
        document.getElementById("ddItems").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
 }

xmlhttp.open("GET", "../code/GetItemsInDD.class.php?id=" + mID + "&method=" + method, true); **// is this statement correct**
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

Change 1 : You may be running the code in an older version of IE, where ActiveXObject is used.

Change 2 : The open() method should not be called if the readyState changes ( as you have written it within the IF block), readyState changes only after the ajax call is initialized by the open() method and then send by the send() method.